# How come stack trace line numbers don't match source code line numbers?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, debugging

My app crashed with an NPE on my device. In the Stack trace received with ACRA, the line numbers refer to two source code classes, `SQLiteStatement` and `SQLiteDatabase`. For `SQLiteDatabase`, none of the line numbers match the lines numbers in any of the source code versions. My device doesn't have a custom ROM. It's a Galaxy S2 running Android 4.03.

Here's the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.releaseAndUnlock(SQLiteStatement.java:290)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:96)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:2025)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1965)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:690)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransactionNonExclusive(SQLiteDatabase.java:605)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.acquireAndLock(SQLiteStatement.java:247)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:112)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1844)
at com.mydomain.myapp.albums.AlbumsData.insertOrIgnore(AlbumsData.java:89)
```

If you look at the source for `SQLiteDataBase` in [its different versions](http://grepcode.com/search?query=sqlitedatabase&n=) you can check for yourselves the numbers don't match.

For example, in Android 4.03's [`SQLiteDataBase` source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java#SQLiteDatabase), `executesql(...)` is found on line 1892 whereas my stack trace says it is located on line 2025.

How is this possible?

<sub>(Please note I'm *not* asking about the source of the NPE)</sub>

Comment: Something isn't running the code you think it is.

Comment: maybe its the catch block line number

Comment: I wouldn't be sure official android sources matches android version on your phone. I think samsung may changed android for it's own purposes.

Comment: You're chasing the wrong bug here. The NPE is caused by the parameters you send the `executeSql` from `AlbumsData.insertOrIgnore`. You're probably sending it a null parameter.

Comment: I have trouble understanding how the app could not be running an instance of the same SQLiteDatabase class as the Android source. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: android is adapted on devices by constructors. google garanties a certain level of compatibility as per the contract with samsung, but that only goes so far.

Comment: @323go This question was only about the line numbers, not the source of the NPE. Sorry if that wasn't clear. I've added a small edit to clarify this.

Comment: @PierreRymiortz I see it like this: samsung guys took android 4.0.3 sources, modified them, added some stuff to different classes (`SQLiteDatabase` seems to be one of them), then build it and got their own version of android. They didn't modify constants that store version of android so you can see that it's 4.0.3.

Comment: anyway, the issue is `setNativeHandle(mDatabase.mNativeHandle);` which indicates you don't have a database opened.

Comment: @Nikita Beloglazov - makes sense. Please write that into an answer so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't be sure official android sources matches android version on your phone. I think samsung may changed android for it's own purposes: samsung guys took android 4.0.3 sources, modified them, added some stuff to different classes (`SQLiteDatabase` seems to be one of them), then build it and got their own version of android. They didn't modify constants that shows version of android so you can see that it's 'still' 4.0.3.

Comment: You were first in the comments with a sensible reason for the diff in line numbers so I accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

All of the internal errors are being caused by this line in your code:

```
com.mydomain.myapp.albums.AlbumsData.insertOrIgnore(AlbumsData.java:89)
```

You need to go to that and figure out what is going on with it. I am in agreement with @323go you are probably passing it a null value of some sort. Once you get that taken care of the internal stuff should go away.

As to why the line numbers are different. You are looking at the bare bones stock system source code. By the time it makes it onto a device and into a consumers hands it will likely have been changed a fair bit, I don't know specifically why or what they would change in the `SQLiteDatabase` class but it appears they have changed something.

Comment: Thanks. I've upvoted your answer. I marked Nikita Beloglazov's answer as accepted since he was first with an explanation (in the comments) for the differing line numbers.